# How to store object data in array using useState hook?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm getting each Object data from for loop and storing in Local array, but i'm unable to set this array by useState hook.

```
const [UserTokens, SetUserTokens] = useState([]);
```

```
{
//For Loop
   Tokens_Array[i] = Object;
}
SetUserTokens((Tokens_Array) => [...Tokens_Array, Object]);
console.log("Tokens Array", Tokens_Array);
console.log("User Tokens", UserTokens);
```

[image]

Comment: The new value of `UserTokens` that you set will be available once your component rerenders, it isn't available immediately after setting your state by accessing `UserTokens`

Answer (score 0):

SetUserTokens is not optimal in the loop, it is rendered once per loop.  You first manipulate your data in the local variable, then act like the code below.

```
    {
//For Loop
   Tokens_Array[i] = Object;


or

Tokens_Array.push(Object)

}
//end loop
SetUserTokens(Tokens_Array);
```